# Why is the boolean modifier adding geometry but not removing the parts in my object?

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I am trying to use the boolean modifier to 'remove' the highlighted objects as can be seen in the first picture. However, when I apply the modifier it does create the geometry - as you can see in the second picture - but it is not removing those parts in my object.

How can I make the boolean modifier work?

Here is the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean object (Circle) has inverted normals which is preventing the boolean working. Check the <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> checkbox on the <kbd>Viewport Overlay</kbd> menu. Red means the normals are inverted.

[image]

Select the Circle, go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select All, then <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. If you then go back into <kbd>Object</kbd> mode and hide the circle in the outliner, you'll see that the boolean has worked.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't check the normals. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I have the Face Orientation checkbox on the Quick (Q) menu here so that it's instantly available in Edit or Object mode.